# Error 430 Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that when I open, one of my macros does not work. If i go into my editor and try to recompile my code, i get the

> Error 430 Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

on this line of code:

```
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("myRange").Cells(1,1) = 1 Then
    Sheets("mysheet").Move before:=Sheets("other sheet") **<<<-- ERROR HERE**
    If Sheets("mysheet (1)").Range("DA1").Value > 0 Then
        Dim n as long
        For n = 2 to Sheets("mysheet (1)").Range("DA1").Value + 1
            Sheets("mysheet (" & n & ")").Move before:=Sheets("other sheet")
        Next n
    End If
End If
```

Comment: That workbook has some `MISSING:` references in its Tools - References?

Comment: No, I checked, no reference missing what so ever. If i disabled macros with no notification. I then at that point can recompile the macros, turn enabled macros on, then I can open it.

Comment: That workbook defines a function or a property called `Sheets`?

Comment: @GSerg, what that code is doing is just taking the sheets("mysheet(1)") and copy move before my "other sheet" tab

Comment: @ThisGuyJustNeedsHelp no that's not what GSerg is asking. He's suggesting this error may arise if you've inadvertently shadowed the built-in `Sheets` with variable named `Sheets` in the enclosing scope. Can you show the rest of the code in this module?

Comment: I don't think i have any variables named Sheets. But I've edited post with whole code.

Comment: You may have a compile problem - try exporting the module(s) in the workbook, save the workbook without macros as an xlsx, import the module(s) and resave with macros as xlsm.

Comment: I've tried that, this is a random issue. Usually it happens after a user have saved the workbook then when they try to reopen it later, they get this or workbooks can't open.

Comment: Are you executing this in *worksheet* module or *standard* one?

Comment: @JohnyL this is running from standard modules code.

Comment: Perhaps, you misspelled sheets' names? 

Comment: @JohnyL unlikely... as it works fine 99.5% of the times.

Comment: As @MathieuGuindon noted in his answer, you've better qualify sheets' name with workbook object they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

That one-liner is doing too many things at once, making it very hard to properly diagnose the problem.

Start by declaring `Worksheet` variables, so that you have an early-bound interface to make your member calls against - note that qualifying with `ActiveWorkbook` is an assumption I'm making here, that should be equivalent to your implicitly-qualified `Sheets` call:

```
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet")

Dim otherSheet As Worksheet
Set otherSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("other sheet")

mySheet.Move Before:=otherSheet
```

If your code gets to the `.Move` method call, it should "just work". If it blows up before that, verify:

- That the sheet name is correctly spelled in the string literal
- That the parent workbook of that sheet is the `ActiveWorkbook`

If all these sheets exist at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook that contains your VBA project), then you don't need any variables - you already have them.

Look in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), all sheet modules have two names. The one in parentheses is the `Name` property; the one before that is the `CodeName`, which you'll find in the *Properties* (F4) toolwindow under `(Name)`. Change that to e.g. `mySheet`, and now the identifier `mySheet` can be used anywhere in this VBA project to refer to *that specific sheet* - regardless of what its "tab name" says.